# Getting table values with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get values from an html table using Python. 
The html looks like this:

```
<table border=1 width=900>
 <tr><td width=50%>
<table>
    <tr><td align=right><b>Invoice #</td><td><input type=text value="1624140" size=12></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Company</td><td><input type=text value="NZone" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Name:</td><td><input type=text value="John Dot" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Address:</td><td><input type=text value="Posie Row, Moscow Road" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>City:</td><td><input type=text value="Co. Dubllin" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Province</td><td><input type=text value="" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Postal Code:</td><td><input type=text value="" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Country:</td><td><input type=text value="IRELAND" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Date:</td><td><input type=text value="24.4.18" size=12></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Sub Total:</td><td><input type=text value="93,24" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Combined Weight:</td><td><input type=text value="1,24" size=40></td></tr>
</table>
```

My code so far is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

request = requests.get('url')

content = request.content

soup = bs(content, 'html.parser')  

table = soup.findChildren('table')[1]

rows = table.findChildren('tr')

for row in rows:
cells = row.findChildren('td')
for cell in cells:
    cell_content = cell.getText()

 print(cell_content)
```

Output is:

```
Invoice #
Company
Name:
Address:
City:
Province
Postal Code:
Country:
Date:
Sub Total:
Combined Weight:
```

I would like final output like the following:

```
Invoice:1624140
Company:NZone
Name:John Dot
Address:Possie Row, Moscow Road
City:Co. Dublin
Province:
Postal Code:
Country:IRELAND
Date:24.4.18
Sub Total:93,24
Combined Weight:1,24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your bottom loop with this:

```
for row in rows:
    [row_title, row_val] = row.findChildren('td')

    print(row_title.getText(), row_val.input['value'])
```

This code unpacks the two cells in each row. It then gets the immediate child text of the left `td` for the row title and drills down into the right `td` for the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = """
<table border=1 width=900>
 <tr><td width=50%>
<table>
    <tr><td align=right><b>Invoice #</td><td><input type=text value="1624140" size=12></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Company</td><td><input type=text value="NZone" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Name:</td><td><input type=text value="John Dot" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Address:</td><td><input type=text value="Posie Row, Moscow Road" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>City:</td><td><input type=text value="Co. Dubllin" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Province</td><td><input type=text value="" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Postal Code:</td><td><input type=text value="" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Country:</td><td><input type=text value="IRELAND" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Date:</td><td><input type=text value="24.4.18" size=12></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Sub Total:</td><td><input type=text value="93,24" size=40></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Combined Weight:</td><td><input type=text value="1,24" size=40></td></tr>
</table>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for (td, inp) in zip(soup.find_all('td', align="right"), soup.find_all('input')):
    print(td.text, inp['value'])
```

Output is:

```
Invoice # 1624140
Company NZone
Name: John Dot
Address: Posie Row, Moscow Road
City: Co. Dubllin
Province 
Postal Code: 
Country: IRELAND
Date: 24.4.18
Sub Total: 93,24
Combined Weight: 1,24
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a dictionary comprehension?

```
d = {k.findChild('td').getText().strip():k.findChild('input')['value'] for k in rows}
```

The result is a dictionary like this:

```
{'Address:': 'Posie Row, Moscow Road',
 'City:': 'Co. Dubllin',
 'Combined Weight:': '1,24',
 'Company': 'NZone',
 'Country:': 'IRELAND',
 'Date:': '24.4.18',
 'Invoice #': '1624140',
 'Name:': 'John Dot',
 'Postal Code:': '',
 'Province': '',
 'Sub Total:': '93,24'}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Assigning row object, maybe you intended to write this? Because your current code has some indentation error. Please see if it fixes your issue.

```
rows = table.findChildren('tr')

for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        cell_content = cell.getText()
        print(cell_content)
```